# Python Shorthand Operator?

Tags: python, shorthand

I was researching some information on the topic of trial division, and I came across this symbol in Python:

```
//=
```

I got this from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) where the code in the example says:

```
n //= p
```

I can't tell what this is supposed to mean, and my research continues to bring poor results in terms of webpages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`//` is integer division and the

```
n //= p
```

syntax is short for

```
n = n // p
```

except the value n is modified directly [if it supports this](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.__ifloordiv__).

Answer (score 5):

When you see an operator followed by an `=`, that is performing the operation and then assigning it into the variable. For example, `x += 2` means `x = x + 2` or add 2 to `x`.

The `//` operator specifically does integer devision instead of floating point division. For example, `5 // 4` gives you `1`, while `5 / 4` gives you `1.25` (in Python 3).

Therefore, `x //= 3` means divide `x` by 3 (in an integer division fashion), and store the value back into `x`. It is equivalent to `x = x // 3`

Comment: It's also important to note that an inplace operation in general case may use a different routines that a standard operation. For example for `list` `L`: `L = L + [1]` creates a different list in memory and assigns it to `L`, but `L += [1]` just extends the list which is the same as `L.extend([1])`. Though, it's not the case for integers since they are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

// is the floor division operator, therefore //= is simply the inplace floor division operator.